# Sources, APIs and techniques for academic data-mining

Tags: ruby, api, data-mining

So I'm gonna do a historical trends analysis for one of my education literature review class. I'm considering use the abstracts and keywords from the peer-reviewed journals since 1970s, I know Springer has an API which might be useful, what other sources/APIs are there? I never did any data-mining and analysis before, I know a bit about ruby and less about python. Any other advices are also welcomed.

Comment: I found Mendeley's api seems to be much more superior than springer. http://apidocs.mendeley.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get abstracts of medical publications (not the fulltext though) using the PubMed API. That'll give you something on the order of a million documents.

Comment: If you're allowed to look at medical publications instead, you may want to look at data mining questions on [BioStar](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/).